# hazelcast imap does't read from backup

Tags: hazelcast

I want to read from backup of the map to improve the performance.But I read the source code of **GetOperation** and find **recordStore.get(dataKey, false)** in this class which make read from backup false.

`

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        MapServiceContext mapServiceContext = mapService.getMapServiceContext();
        result = mapServiceContext.toData(recordStore.get(dataKey, false));
    }
```

`

Then how read from backup of map?

Comment: Why would you expect read-from-backup to help ? Although this is available for some use cases, in a correctly balanced cluster, the node with the backup should be just as busy as the node with the master

Comment: If the get request is located in the backup node,it becomes a local operation if read-from-backup is available.It need't transfer the request to the master node of the data.I think this can make the operation faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `<read-backup-data>` has to be enabled.

Second, it works only on a member, so e.g. when you execute a task in an Executor service, and use an IMap.

This means you need a member-side reference to an Imap proxy. It won't work from a client.

Comment: Thank you,I am clear now.But I can't understand why read-backup-data is designed like this.The common scene is the client side communicates with the service side and performance optimization between them is more significant.

Comment: Yeah, we get it too. It is in our backlog... Stay tuned plz!

Comment: Remember not to expect this to be beneficial. An operation that originates on Server A could use backup data from Server A rather than a network hop to the master copy on Server B -- one less network hop, hence a benefit on server originated operations. A client that can call Server A with the backup or Server B with the master copy will have the same number of network hops, so if the servers are equally loaded (they should be in a well balanced grid) they should be equally responsive, and there will be little difference in the turnaround time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration element `<read-backup-data>` in Hazelcast XML configuration. When it is set to "true", it should be enabled.

Comment: This is the official doc says.But what I find in code is not that way.It will not read from the backup.

Comment: You shouldn't use `com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapServiceContext` as it's an internal class, the `impl` indicates it an implementation class. Use `com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance.getMap(String)` in the API.

Comment: I am looking into how the  **GetOperation** is operated.This is hazelcast's source code,not my code.